# Add target to button on a tableView row on Apple Watch

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit

I have a row controller set up with a button. How can I make it so when it's pressed, the background image changes with an animation? I can't do it in the RowController file because you cannot call `animateWithDuration`.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement the following method for row selection and in this method you can put the animation code.

```
-(void)table:(WKInterfaceTable *)table didSelectRowAtIndex:(NSInteger)rowIndex{}
```

Also Apple do not allow to programmatically set target for `WKInterafaceButton`, you need to implement that via storyboard.